# What was the nakshatra and gotra of Ravana?

Tags: astrology, ravana, nakshatra

I was looking for details about Ravana's nakshatra but could not find reliable information.Is there any Texts that mention Ravana's nakshatra and other astrological details?

For the gotra,I found out that Ravana's gotra was the Devgana Gotra,but I don't know which Texts mention this.

If possible please cite all the available Texts.

Comment: Goutamasa or kapisa gotra Ravana has a shrap that he will be killed by the person named by his gothra that is kapisa means monkey means lord Hanuman
Kapi means monkey .

Comment: There is no Devagana gotra, this is just invented nonsense. Rāvaṇa was the grandson of Pulastya. But there's no gotra named Pulastya. @Das Matsya Purāṇa mentions that Pulastya upon seeing that his descendants were rākṣasas, adopted a son of Agastya, and so the descendants of Pulastya i.e. Paulastyas bear the Agastya gotra and are actual descendants of Agastya. So, it's actually hard to know which gotra Rāvaṇa used, it seems that Pulastya had disowned him.